# Jshint: error : d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using angular-nvd3 in my application. While running jshint task, it shows error: d3 is not defiend.

Here is my controller using d3 :

```
        function measurementsCtrl() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.options = {
              chart: {
                  type: 'lineChart',
                  height: 450,
                  margin : {
                      top: 20,
                      right: 20,
                      bottom: 40,
                      left: 55
                  },
                  x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                  y: function(d){ return d.y; },

                  xAxis: {
                      axisLabel: 'Time (ms)'
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      axisLabel: 'Voltage (v)',
                      tickFormat: function(d){
                          return d3.format('.02f')(d);
                      },
                      axisLabelDistance: -10
                  },
                  callback: function(chart){
                      console.log("!!! lineChart callback !!!");
                  }
              }      
          }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check in your .jshintrc file

if "d3" is defined under globals

```
 "globals": {
    "d3": true
}
```